# Running WhiteNoise locally for Django development

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, whitenoise

I'm trying to serve static files on a Django project with `DEBUG = False`. I found the WhiteNoise project and configured it according to the docs, and my project works great when deployed to Amazon Web Services. However, when I try to run the project locally, the static files aren't served. I've tried running `python3 manage.py runserver --nostatic` and also adding `'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` per the docs [here](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development). The static files still aren't being served locally, though. Does anyone know if there are some other settings or configurations I should be changing?

Comment: Did you run collectstatic?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I did everything as mentioned in this post + collectstatic too. However, I am unable to identify if it is Whitenoise that is serving my files or django. Please help.